# How to tracing a request through a chain of microservices end-to-end?

Tags: go, stackdriver, distributed-tracing, google-cloud-trace, opencensus

I am using OpenCensus in Go to push tracing data to Stackdriver for calls involving a chain of 2 or more micro services and I noticed that I get many traces which contain spans only for certain services but not the entire end to end call.

At the moment I attribute this to the fact that not all calls are traced (only a certain sample) and each service decides whether to trace its current span or not.

Is this the way it is intended to work? Is there any way to make sure when a trace is sampled, it is done so by all services in the call chain?

Answer (score 0):

Architecturally I will say when you are developing your microservices make sure your API Gateway creates a unique id like GUID, which gets propagated through all the microservices & similarly you make sure that you have log aggregator which will be collecting logs from all the services & finally you are getting nice tracebility of request.

Comment: Thank you but opencensus seems to already generate this ID on each span along the way. I am not talking about logging or metrics here, just tracing