# StackDriver Trace across Cloud/Services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

What if I have an application that works across cloud services. Eg. AWS Lambda will call Google CloudRun service and I want to have my traces work across these. Isit possible? I guess I will have to somehow pass a trace ID and set it when I need it? But I see no way to set a trace ID?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/57894336/322020

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the list of supported language/backend combinations, we see that both GCP (Stackdriver) and AWS (X-Ray) are supported.  See: [Exporters](https://opencensus.io/exporters/).  What this means is that you can instrument either (or both) of your AWS Lambda or GCP CloudRun applications with OpenCensus calls.    I suspect you will have to dig deep to determine the specifics but this feels like a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If an OpenCensus library is available for your programming language, you can simplify the process of creating and sending trace data by using OpenCensus. In addition to being simpler to use, OpenCensus implements batching which might improve performance [click here](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/overview#tracing_interface).

The Stackdriver Trace API allows you to send and retrieve latency data to and from Stackdriver Trace. There are two versions of the API:

1. Stackdriver Trace API v1 is fully supported.
2. Stackdriver Trace API v2 is in Beta release.

The client libraries for Trace automatically generate the trace_id and the span_id. You need to generate the values for these fields if you don't use the Trace client libraries or the OpenCensus client libraries. In this case, you should use a pseudo-random or random algorithm. Don't derive these fields from need-to-know data or from personally identifiable information, for details please [click here](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/reference/?hl=en_US&_ga=2.86513745.-83103782.1573314853#generating_trace_id_and_span_id).